# Auto Incremnt Primary ID with current year as prefix

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

What should I do to create auto incremented primary id in MySQL with prefix of the current year plus a number of digits(appended),e.g. 2012000001, 2012000002... if year changes it will begin with 1 again as in 2013000001, 2012000002...

Thanks.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

julian

Comment: May i ask why you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, that is not possible.

Mysql just found the greatest id in the table, and increments it by one. So the operation you described is not possible if you use **auto-incremented** values, you had to manually update the id's when inserting, which is not really a recommended technique.

Answer (score 0):

While I recommend against this approach, at least for a PK, if you want to do it you must use an [`INSERT TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).